# How do browsers interpret hrefs that start with "http:/"?

Tags: html, hyperlink, cross-browser

Some of my users are creating links that look like

```
<a href='http:/some_local_path'>whatever</a>
```

I've noticed that Firefox interprets this as

```
<a href='/some_local_path'>whatever</a>
```

Can I count on this occurring in all browsers? Or should I remove the `http:/`s myself?

Comment: You better make sure that this will never happen. The first form is invalid and no one can guarantee that it will work as expected. The second one is ok, though.

Comment: Neither form works for me in IE8.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an unusual URL, but is not invalid.  The URL spec says that omitted components are defaulted from the base url, which can be provided explicitly in a `<base>` tag, or absent that, the current URL of the page.

When a browser sees `/some_local_path`, it is missing a scheme and a host, so it takes them from the base url.  When your users put `http:/some_local_path`, it has an explicit scheme, but is missing a host, so the host defaults to the base url.  If your page is an http: page, then the two URLs will be interpreted identically.

All that said, those URLs are almost certainly not what your users intended.  You'll be helping them if you point out their error.

Answer (score 1):

It's always best to validate data entered by users. Inevitably, you'll get something unexpected.